# Storing strings in an ArrayList in a synchronized method

Tags: java, runtime

So I have this program that will execute a command in cmd and then get its output. The output is collected inside the log() method. Originally, I was printing out the output and it printed fine. Next, I also wanted to store the output in an ArrayList. For some reason, when storing it in an ArrayList, only the first line is added, while when printing, all the lines are printed.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Executor {
    private ArrayList<String> currentOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void executeCommand(String command) {
        command = "cmd /c "+ command;
        try {
            log(command);
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            logOutput(process.getInputStream(), "");
            logOutput(process.getErrorStream(), "Error: ");
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void logOutput(InputStream inputStream, String prefix) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                synchronized (this) {

                    log(prefix + scanner.nextLine());
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        }).start();
    }



    private synchronized void log(String message) {
        currentOutput.add(message);    // Only adds the output the first time the method is called
        System.out.println(message);   // Prints out all of the outputs
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getOutput() {
        return currentOutput;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you called getOutput and printed that, so could you provide a sample output of the code where you called that and output of it? At the very least the method getOutput() must also be synchronized. You need to cover both writing and reading to objects that are going to be touched from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for the 2 threads to complete their work.

You need to change `logOutput()` to return the `Thread` object, and you need to call `join()` on the 2 returned threads right after the `waitFor()` call.

```
public void executeCommand(String command) {
    ...
    Thread t1 = logOutput(process.getInputStream(), "");
    Thread t2 = logOutput(process.getErrorStream(), "Error: ");
    process.waitFor();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    ...
}

private Thread logOutput(InputStream inputStream, String prefix) {
    Thread t = ...
    t.start();
    return t;
}
```

Also, this code is redundant, since the `log()` method is `synchronized`. Remove the `synchronized (this)` block.

```
...
synchronized (this) {
    log(prefix + scanner.nextLine());
}
...
```